# Multi-process, using Queue & Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I have a Producer process that runs and puts the results in a Queue 
I also have a Consumer function that takes the results from the Queue and processes them , for example:

```
def processFrame(Q,commandsFile):
    fr = Q.get()
    frameNum = fr[0]
    Frame = fr[1]
    #        
    #   Process the frame
    #
    commandsFile.write(theProcessedResult)
```

I want to run my consumer function using multiple processes, they number should be set by user:

```
processes = raw_input('Enter the number of process you want to use: ')
```

i tried using Pool:

```
pool = Pool(int(processes))
pool.apply(processFrame, args=(q,toFile))
```

when i try this , it returns a RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance.
what does that mean?

I also tried to use a list of processes:

```
while (q.empty() == False):
    mp = [Process(target=processFrame, args=(q,toFile)) for x in range(int(processes))]
    for p in mp:
        p.start()
    for p in mp:
        p.join()
```

This one seems to run, but not as expected.
it using multiple processes on same frame from Queue, doesn't Queue have locks?
also ,in this case the number of processes i'm allowed to use must divide the number of frames without residue(reminder) - for example:
if i have 10 frames i can use only 1,2,5,10 processes. if i use 3,4.. it will create a process while Q empty and wont work.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to recycle the procces until q is empty u should just try to do somthing like that:

code1:

```
       def proccesframe():
           while(True):
               frame = queue.get()
               ##do something
```

your procces will be blocked until there is something in the queue
i dont think that's a good idie to use multiproccess on the cunsomer part , you should use them on the producer.
if u want to terminate the procces when the queue is empty u can do something like that:

code2:

```
       def proccesframe():
           while(!queue.empty()):
                 frame = queue.get()
                 ##do something
           terminate_procces()
```

### update:

if u want to use multiproccesing in the consumer part just do a simple loop and add code2 , then you will be able to close your proccess when u finish doing stuff with the queue.

Comment: all possible combinations of multiplicity between producers and consumers processes are acceptable and are standard patters in computer science.

Comment: the main purpose of this assignment is to use multi-process on the consumer, because of its long processing time.
the producer reads frames very fast compared to the time it takes to process them

Comment: allright then u can see my update , just add a loop that waits till the queue is empty and then terminate the proccesess.

Comment: i hoped i helped you if it still doesnt work u may contact me in private i would love to help you

Comment: Thanks, but i don't see how your loop works in mp.
it will just go over the queue and process its items in a serial processing until queue is empty.

i have tried some other ways ( edited my original post) .
still haven't found how to implement this.

Comment: you got sevral proccesses which all go threw that loop and each proccess takes 1 item from the queue till its empty and then you terminate them, it should work for you. like i said before i would love to help you implement it in your code

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what are you trying to accomplish from your explanation, but have you considered using [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) with its methods [map](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) or [map_async](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async)?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from foo import bar # your function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(4) # your number of processes
    result = p.map_async(bar, [("arg #1", "arg #2"), ...])
    print result.get()
```

It collects result from your function in unordered(!) iterable and you can use it however you wish.

**UPDATE**

I think you should not use queue and be more straightforward:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_frame(fr): # PEP8 and see the difference in definition
    # magic
    return result # and result handling!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(4) # your number of processes
    results = p.map_async(process_frame, [fr_1, fr_2, ...])
    # Do not ever write or manipulate with files in parallel processes
    # if you are not 100% sure what you are doing!
    for result in results.get():
        commands_file.write(result)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
import time

def f(x):
    return x*x

def g(yr):
    with open("result.txt", "ab") as f:
        for y in yr:
            f.write("{}\n".format(y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)

    while True:
        # here you fetch new data and send it to process
        new_data = [random.randint(1, 50) for i in range(4)]
        pool.map_async(f, new_data, callback=g)
```

Some example how to do it and I updated the algorithm to be "infinite", it can be only closed by interruption or kill command from outside. You can use also apply_async, but it would cause slow downs with result handling (depending on speed of processing).

I have also tried using long-time open result.txt in global scope, but every time it hit deadlock.

Comment: i tried using Pool, but i get a Runtime Error:

"RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

Comment: i edited my original question, hope my explanation is better now

Comment: You should not use queue with Pool. You simple set up some iterable (even a function if you know what you are doing) and let it work. Then you take the function results in iterable and do the finishing job you do in process frame after result.get() in my case. But if you use processFrame as a parallel processing after getFrames then answer will be little bit more complex. You should then specify callback function in map_async which should by to my knowing locked and you would have to go that way. So once again, what are you trying accomplish? I need a bigger picture.

Comment: I have a file that contains frames that were taken by a camera. I need to take those frames, process them ( find peak in each frame) and write to a file the place (x,y) of the peak in each frame.  i need to do the processing in MP, each process works on a different frame , that's why i am tring to use Queue

Comment: this way i can continue reading the frames from the file, while processing the frames that i already read simultaneously.

Comment: Then my update should be exactly your problem solver and if you wish process result truly sequentially in main thread then take look at [multiprocessing.Pool.imap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap). It is good use when you expect the algorithm be infinite (you can fetch in the meantime next data and send it to pool).

Comment: ok , i understand your proposal. but how do i fetch my new "frames" and send it to Pool while Pool is working on current frames?

Comment: I took different approach from what I suggested, but it should do what you want now.